# Ошибка non-void function does not return a value in all control paths

Tags: c, cs50

Итак, та самая non-void function у меня следующая:

```
int find_length (long card_num)
{
    int len;
    for (len = 0; card_num > 0; card_num / 10, len++)
    return len;
}
```

Вроде прошу же вывести переменную len, а она int, и функция у меня int... Что не так? В каких там путях моя функция не выдает значение?

Comment: `return len;` - это тело цикла.

Comment: Забыли 2 вещи. 1) `;` сразу после `for(...)` 2) `=` сразу после `/` в `card_num / 10` / Т.е. правильно будет вот так -- `for (len = 0; card_num > 0; card_num /= 10, len++);
    return len;`

Comment: @avp благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Твоя функция эквивалента такой:

```
int find_length(long card_num)
{
  if (card_num > 0) return 0;
}
```

Очевидно, что для остальных случаев `return` отсутствует.